# ^M characters showing in CSV file generated using opencsv.CSVWriter

Tags: java, csv

**Csv writing Code**

```
private void writeReversalPendingCsv(List<String[]> elements) throws IOException {
    BufferedWriter writer = null;
    CSVWriter csvWriter = null;
    String fileName = null;
    ..
    writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(filePath));
            Character sep = new Character('|');
            csvWriter = new CSVWriter(writer,
                    sep,
                    new Character('\0'),
                    CSVWriter.DEFAULT_ESCAPE_CHARACTER,
                    CSVWriter.DEFAULT_LINE_END);
            for (String[] row : elements) {
                 csvWriter.writeNext(row);
            }
```

Csv in vim mode -

```
2|value|hello^M
2|value2|hello2
```

**CSV reading**

Before this writing part, I also read a csv of the same format.

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(file.getInputStream());
            List<String[]> reversalPending = new ArrayList<>();
            scanner.useDelimiter("\\n");
            int totalRows = 0;
            while (scanner.hasNext()) {
                   ..
                   String line = scanner.next();
                   String[] arr = line.split("\\|");
                   .. processing 
                   if(processing fails) {
                       reversalPending.add(arr);
                       writeReversalPendingCsv(reversalPending);
                   }
            }
```

I process each row and depending on some condition, take these rows and write them into a csv file.

So, my overall logic is -

- read csv file
- process each row
- dump unprocessed rows into csv file.

If I use the csv file from output of csv writing and feed in the same flow, the processing works but I get an extra ^M -

```
2|value|hello^M^M
2|value2|hello2
```

Should I prevent this? How, if so?

Comment: in vim `^M` is used to display `\r` (carriage return character). `\r\n` is used on Windows as ["line ending"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline), while unix uses `\n`. maybe your input file uses `\r\n`, the `\r` is not getting "eaten" by `Scanner` and ends up in the strings because you specify `\n` as delimiter. try using `scanner.useDelimiter("\r\n");`

Comment: Thanks, worked pls add as answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in vim `^M` is used to display `\r` carriage return character (see [this](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/digraph.html#digraph-table) for other "weird looking characters").

`\r\n` is used by windows as "[line ending](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline)", while unix uses just `\n`.

what is happening here is that your input file uses `\r\n` as line ending, the `\r` is not getting "eaten" by `Scanner` and ends up in the strings because you specify only `\n` as delimiter.

setting `\r\n` as delimiter fixes the issue or better `\r?\n` since input of `useDelimiter()` is a regex, `?` after `\r` means that `\r` is optional and in this way it will work properly with both files written from windows and files written from unix-like systems.

```
scanner.useDelimiter("\r?\n");
```